# Where are the Thunderbolt components?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, sata

I've been looking around for a few weeks now and still dont see any Thunderbolt adapters, like a SATA/eSATA adapter or anything similar, is it still too soon ? i just havent seen anything on Newegg or anywhere else.

Comment: Any word on Thunderbolt --> FireWire adapters? I'm looking to replace my ageing MacBook with one of the upcoming 13 inch Airs. I have a FireWire sound card though and I'd need an adapter to hook it up.

Comment: For those interested, someone pointed me here --> http://www.sonnettech.com/news/nab2011/index.html.

Comment: Would you perhaps edit this to make it less of a temporary and subjective. What exactly are you looking to do with eSATA or similar adaptors?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Apple Thunderbolt Display:

http://www.apple.com/displays/

It's a Thunderbolt - Firefwire, USB, Ethernet, and Thunderbolt adapter.

Answer (score 0):

#### Currently Thunderbolt is advanced hi tech [Vapor Ware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_Nukem_Forever).

There are a few prototype external drives floating around but until I can physically plug <del>something</del> multiple Thunderbolt enabled devices (as promised) in to my MacBook Pro it doesn't exist.

I love my MacBook Pro but Apple mis-represented Thunderbolt in it's initial marketing.  The multi monitor display capability specs were removed from the website.

.

[image]

Comment: To be fair, you can plug in a monitor that supports Mini DisplayPort.

Comment: Very true.  I have mine plugged into a 27" Cinema Display.  I just felt like I was mislead into thinking I would be able to use Thunderbolt to connect 2 displays and an external drive to the port. (It's coming soon)

Comment: Reality begs to differ if you actually have two Thunderbolt ports (27" iMac): http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/03/apple-imac-hands-on-with-dual-30-inch-displays-video/ Now if someone released a monitor that actually chained correctly...

Comment: @Chris_O regarding multiple monitors - you can do that. http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/03/apple-imac-hands-on-with-dual-30-inch-displays-video/ How's that for your "Thunderbolt doesn't exist"?

Answer (score 0):

See the recent Computex event for information on that. Promise and LaCie demoed Thunderbolt-capable storage devices slated for a Summer release.